# Retrofit GET query с параметры

Tags: android, запрос, retrofit

Есть такой API 
https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/exchange_rates?json&date=01.12.2014
с помощью retrofit хочу получить json с указанными параметрами (датой)

Вот мой интерфейс

```
public interface PrivatApi {

@GET("p24api/exchange_rates")
Call<List<Rate>> getSelectedData(@Query("date") String date);
}
```

правильно ли я передаю параметр дата? мой метод не работает!(

```
          private void getRatesOnDate( ) {
             retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
             service = retrofit.create(PrivatApi.class);
             rates = new ArrayList<>();
             String selectedate = "31.03.2014";

             service.getSelectedData("", selectedate).enqueue(new     Callback<List<Rate>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<List<Rate>> call, Response<List<Rate>> response) {

          rates.addAll(response.body());
          }
          @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<List<Rate>> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.e("MyLog", "onFailure" + t.toString());
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Выкидывает ошибку  onFailurecom.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $

Comment: Покажите код связанный с запросом. Весь

Comment: добавил код в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

```
public interface PrivatApi {

@GET("p24api/exchange_rates")
Call<List<Rate>> getSelectedData(@Query("json") String json, @Query("date") String date);
}
```

А вызывать так

```
getSelectedData("", date);
```

Comment: не помогло, но ошибка поменялась  onFailurejava.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: Нашел у себя ошибку в описании файла

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй:

```
public interface PrivatApi {

@GET("p24api/exchange_rates")
Call<String> getSelectedData(@Query("json") String json, @Query("date") String date);
}
```

или

```
public interface PrivatApi {

@GET("p24api/exchange_rates")
Call<String> getSelectedData(@Query("json&date") String dateInJson);
}
```

если всё успешно создавай Обьект в зависимости от json ответа, меняй Call string на Call твой_обект и не забудь включить GSONBuilder в retrofit build и посети http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/